Am creating an AR app for architectural visualization. The app must show the 3d model of the house in its correct location and true to scale
The problem is that the camera olny augments the 3d model when it is tracking the image target. I have tried using extended tracking feature but still the 3D image disappears when the camera is not tracking the image target. Is there a way I can allow the 3d model to be pined on a certain location afeter the image target is tracked?
I tried using the script below and it's giving me the following error message: The type or namespace name 'ITrackableEventHandler' could not be found(are you missing a  using directive or an assembly reference?
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class KeepObjectVisible : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{
    private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
    private bool isTracking = false;

    void Start()
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
        }
    }

    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
        TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            OnTrackingFound();
        }
        else if (previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED &&
                 newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NO_POSE)
        {
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
        else
        {
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
    }

    private void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        isTracking = true;
        SetChildrenActive(true);
    }

    private void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        isTracking = false;
        // Here, we do not deactivate the children to keep the object visible.
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!isTracking)
        {
            // Logic to keep the object visible and possibly maintain its last known position.
        }
    }

    private void SetChildrenActive(bool active)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            child.gameObject.SetActive(active);
        }
    }
}


I would read this article on Device Tracking and how to enable Extended Tracking in your Unity project.

You need to enable the Device Tracker to enable Extended Tracking. You can find this setting in the Vuforia Configuration.

You can then use the Default Observer Event Handler component on the Image Target Behaviour to control the Status for which your target should be tracked. For example, you can set it to Tracked or Extended Tracked.


I don't think there's a need to control this in a script. The ITrackableEventHandler and TrackableBehaviour is from the 9.8 Vuforia Engine API and has long been deprecated. So if you want to script the behaviour, you should use the TargetStatus(Status, StatusInfo) instead. See this page for an example.
